# NullPointerException when calling a method from another class

Tags: java, netbeans

I have initialized all my classes correctly although not shown in the code. I have tested if the source of the error was in my `textfield` but it wasn't. the "s" in the `MainForm` class is the initialization of the `Sqlstatement` class. There is one error here which is shown in the code below

my `new_user` class

```
public new_user() {
    initComponents();

    try{

        mf = new MainForm();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}private void save_user_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    try{
        user = uname_input_txt.getText();
        pass = pass_input_txt.getText();

        //ERROR HERE
        if(mf.search_for_dupe_user(user) == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username not available");
        }else{
            mf.new_user(user, pass);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New user added.");
            this.dispose();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There is one here too which is shown in the code.

my `main_form` class

```
public void new_user(String user, String pass)throws SQLException{
    try{
        s.new_user(user, pass);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean search_for_dupe_user(String user)throws SQLException{

   boolean result = false;

   try{ 
        //ERROR HERE
        if(s.search_for_dupe_user(user) == true){
            result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;
        }
   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return result;
}
```

my `sqlstatement` class

```
public void new_user(String user, String pass)throws SQLException{
    try{
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into users (user_num, username, password) values(null,'"+user+"','"+pass+"')");
        stmt.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean search_for_dupe_user(String user)throws SQLException{

   boolean result= false;

   ResultSet rs = null;
   try{
        rs = statement.executeQuery("select username from users where username='"+user+"'");

        if(rs.next())
        {
           result = true;
        }

        else
        {
           result = false;
        }
   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return result;
}
```

my stacktrace

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at MainForm.search_for_dupe_user(MainForm.java:3151)
>
> at new_user.save_user_btnActionPerformed(new_user.java:129)

Comment: The stacktrace tells you which line it occurs at. Which line is that?

Comment: The linked Q&A explains how to debug NPEs.  You haven't provided us with the necessary information, so the best thing is for you to read the answers (thoroughly) and do it yourself.

Comment: @JaredT line 3151 is in the main_form class below the comment ERRPR HERE